# How does entropy ensure that isolated thermal processes are 100% irreversible?

Tags: entropy

[image]

How can anyone prove that molecules in figure C will never return to their original positions in figure A? It will be more believable to say that the chance is very slim.

Answer (score 0):

It can be seen from the Gibbs free energy:

$$dG=dH-TdS$$

Lets assume that it is possible and the situation reverses from Figure c to a. The change in entropy of this system is negative ($dS<0$) because it goes from a disorderly to orderly state. We can see in that case $dG>0$ assuming $dH>0$, this indicates this is non-spontaneous and will therefore likely not happen without external energy input.